# @BindingConversion Double to String with different amount of decimal places?

Tags: android, android-databinding

When using `@BindingConversion`, what if I once want to convert a Double to a String with two decimal places and once with three decimal places? Is that somehow possible or can I only define one global kind of conversion from Double to String?

Answer (score 0):

You can use static `@BindingConversion` method with conjunction of global variable. Like

```
var isEven = false

@BindingConversion("yourMethod")
fun doubleToString(aDouble:Double):String{
return String.format(if(isEven)"%.3f" else "%.2f", aDouble).also {isEven!=isEven}
```

}